# Ax - check if field is selected from database

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Is there a method to check if a field is retrieved from the database? I created some logic which is being called from different locations. But from some locations, the table buffer was selected using a field list. I would like to only execute the query again if the field isn't retrieved. The queries to fetch the correct record are quite heavy and in most cases the field will be empty.

```
Common o;
o = args.caller();
if(!isFieldRetrievedFromDatabase(o.(fieldId)))
{
    o = refetch(o);
}
//execute logic for o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`o.isFieldDataRetrieved`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.isfielddataretrieved.aspx).

> `xRecord.isFieldDataRetrieved` Method:
>
> Checks whether the data of the given field has been retrieved
>
> > true if the data has been retrieved; otherwise, false.